# Add time with integer number in python

Tags: python, datetime, time, addition

I want to get current time and add it with an integer of hours.  Example now is 11.00pm, May 12, 2019.  I want to add 3 hours more. So the result would be 2.00 am May 13, 2019.  Please help me to datetime + hours(integer type)

```
import datetime

currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()
print('Now is: '+ str(currentDT))
hours = int(input()) #any hours you want
result = currentDT + hours #it will get the errors here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `datetime.now` to obtain the current time, and add a `datetime.timedelta`:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

n_hours = 3
date = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=n_hours)
```

---

```
print(datetime.now())
# 2019-05-12 19:16:51.651376

print(date)
# 2019-05-12 22:16:51.464890
```

Comment: how about input() is a random number? I mean I wanna add any integer number here, it is not a default number.

Comment: Just use a variable?

Comment: @BrianHuynh Change the `hours` argument in the `timedelta` function to whatever you want.  You specified 3 hours in your post and hence 3 hours was put in the answer.

Comment: You're welcome @BrianHuynh. As mentioned, don't forget to accept (green check under the voting options)

Comment: Thank you Yatu. Thank you stackover give me hope that I can code and do the right job for myself. Thank you 5* from Vietnam